# identity server 4 get email claim without using Profile

Tags: identityserver4

How can I configure Identity Server Core to pass user email, in a Hybrid flow, without including the "Profile" identity Resource?

I want my server to know the least information possible about the user, so I only require user emails for users to create an account. My consent is only asking the user to authorize for id and email both required.

I am using entity framework Stores to persist the data + Asp.net Core Identity for user management. I populate the DB from the Config shown below.

This is what I have done so far, but I am not receiving the user a claim with the user email. I am receiving the "sid" though.

```
public class Config
{
    // scopes define the resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {

        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email
            {
                Required = true
            }
        };
    }


    // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
             new Client
            {
                ClientId = "MyClient",
                ClientName = "MyClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                RequireConsent = true,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:27919/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:27919" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }



        };
    }
}
```

On the client side I am doing:

```
// middleware for external openid connect authentication
        var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            SignInScheme = "Identity.External",
            SignOutScheme = "Identity",

            DisplayName = "MyClient",
            Authority = Constants.AuthServer.BaseUrl,

            ClientId = "MyClient",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            ResponseType = "code id_token",

            //Scopes are entered below, outside this constructor

            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,


            RequireHttpsMetadata = false   //TODO: make true, it is false for development only


        };
        //Adding Scopes
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that in the Account controller corresponding to Asp.net Identity an email claim must be created when a user is created, so add:

```
 user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<string>
            {
                ClaimType = "email",
                ClaimValue = model.Email
            });
```

following each user creation:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is an old Question, but I searched a long time for a solution of my similar problem.

The goal was to set **`AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true`** to true in the Config.cs of IdentityServer4. Then you get `prefered_username` and `name` in the claims.

```
new Client
{
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true,

    ClientId = "MyID",
    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("MySecret".Sha256())},

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc",  "https://app.gform.de/signin-oidc" },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc","https://app.gform.de/signout-callback-oidc" },
   
            
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>    {
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "api1"
    }
}
```